# html_entity_decode for twig (opencart)

Tags: twig, opencart

im trying to output an attribute of a product on my product page (opencart v3).

The attribute is called 'technicaldetails' and it works just fine using this code:

```
{% if attribute_groups %}
  {% for attribute_group in attribute_groups %}
    {% if attribute_group.name == 'technicaldetails' %}
      {% for attribute in attribute_group.attribute %}
        {{ attribute.text }}
      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

but the technical details field have unstyled list stored in it.. and this outputs the complete html instead of rendering the list.

ive tried using `{{ attribute.text|e }}` and `{{ attribute.text|raw }}` and many other alternatives i could find.. but each time is just throws out the html and not render it..

in php this used to work.

```
<?php echo html_entity_decode($attribute['text']); ?>
```

so how can i decode the html now as i cant use php in twig and there is no html_entity_decode in twig either :(

looking forward for somehelp :)

much appreciated

thanks.

Comment: the attribute.text is stored in DB as an html.. it gets encoded thats why i was using `html_entity_decode()` function and that used to work.. but now opencart uses twig and i don't know a way to fix this :(

Comment: Is it stored as raw HTML, or encoded HTML?  Like when you view the database directly are tags stored as `<>` or `&lt;&gt;`?  If the answer is the latter you might need to create a `htmlspecialchars_decode` custom Twig filter

Comment: this is how it is in the database (Copied directly from there)
```<ul class='technicaldetails'>  
 <li>1</li>  
 <li>2</li>  
 <li>3</li>  
 <li>4</li>
</ul>```

Comment: Using `|raw` should work then, unless OpenCart is doing an additional escape on whatever you are using.  Or maybe they don't allow what you are trying to do for safety reasons?  Try making a Twig filter and using that

Comment: `|raw` gives out the same thing. so is `|e`

Comment: Okay in that case I'd try making a custom Twig filter and using that.

Comment: i literally have no clue about creating any custom twig filter.. as a matter of fact today is the first time i even came across twig itself :(

there has to be a filter for html_entity_decode function already made or similar? :(

Comment: Are you using Symfony?

Comment: im working on open cart v3.0.2.0

Comment: If you're not using Symfony and don't have access to create your own custom filters then you might have to raise the issue with OpenCart

Comment: Ive posted the question on opencart forum as well.. i was hoping i might get the answers here more quickly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just register the `html_entity_decode` function in `twig`.
The most simple way is to look where `twig` is loaded and add the following code,

```
$twig->addFilter(new \Twig_Simple_Filter, 'html_entity_decode', 'html_entity_decode');
```

After that you can just do the following in your `twig` templates

```
{{ attribute.text|html_entity_decode }}
```

**UPDATE:** For Opencart 3.0.3.7 version filter should be like this:

```
$twig->addFilter(new \Twig\TwigFilter('html_entity_decode','html_entity_decode'));
```

Comment: worked like a charm!!! thanks alot! now just need to see how to make it so that updates wont remove this again :D

Answer (score 1):

Find file

```
document_root/system/library/template/twig.php
```

Just after

```
$this->twig = new \Twig_Environment($loader, $config);
```

add following code

```
$twig->addFilter(new \Twig_SimpleFilter('html_entity_decode', 'html_entity_decode'));
```

After doing this, you must went to admin to reload all modifications in menu Extensions -> modifications.
After that you can do the following in all twig files *.twig

```
{{ attribute.text|html_entity_decode }}
```