# How to properly setup schema.org for Opencart

Tags: opencart, schema.org

Im finding that  "availability":   "{{ stock|striptags }}", returns translated value in Opencart , which is invalid 
-Msg from GSC- >>Invalid enum value in field "availability"<<
Any clue how to override that translation ?

Have tried everything i know... This is my product.twig

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context":         "http://schema.org/",
  "@type":            "Product",
  "url" :               "{{ base }}",
  "name":             "{{ heading_title }}",
  "image":            "{{ thumb }}",
  "description":      "{{ description|striptags|slice(0, 200) }}",
  {% if tbData.common['manufacturers_enabled'] and manufacturer %}
  "brand":{
    "@type":          "Thing",
    "name":           "{{ manufacturer }}"
  },
  {% endif %}
  {% if rating %}
  "aggregateRating":{
    "@type":          "AggregateRating",
    "ratingValue":    "{{ rating }}",
    "reviewCount":    "{{ reviews|number_format }}"
  },
  {% endif %}
  "offers":{`enter code here`enter code here`
    "@type":          "Offer",
    "priceCurrency":  "{{ tbData.currency_code }}",
    {% if not special %}
    "price":          "{{ product_info.price_num }}",
    {% else %}
    "price":          "{{ product_info.special_num }}",
    {% endif %}
        "availability":   "{{ stock|striptags }}",
    "seller":{
      "@type":        "Organization",
      "name":         "{{ product_info['store_name'] }}"
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I might not be reading the question right, but if the data's coming from OpenCart encoded then you could try either decoding it (with html_entity_decode) before it gets to the template, or within the template by modifying Twig to give you access to html_entity_decode (explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45988196/957246).

Comment: No,
question was for schema.org setup Opencart 3x